# AutoHotKey – ellegant way of waiting until a system dialog box becomes able to accept keystrokes?

Tags: windows, windows-8, script, autohotkey, dialog

Standard system **Print dialog** or **Save dialog** is swallowing keys sent *immediately after opening*. Is there a way how to send keys successfully as soon as possible?

**Details:**

Let's have some simple use case of Print dialog, i.e. if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in Internet Explorer. Once it opens, I just want to send <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to press the **Print** button as soon as possible. But the following script does not work:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class IEFrame
F2::
    Send ^p
    WinWait, Print,, 2
    Send !p   ; this has no effect if sent immediately
Return
#IfWinActive
```

It starts working when I insert `Sleep 500` before `Send !p`. But perhaps 500 ms won't be enough in some cases. Is there some ellegant way how to insert keystrokes ASAP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class IEFrame

F2:: 
    Send ^p
    WinWait, Print ahk_class #32770     ; Waits until the specified window exists
    IfWinNotActive, Print ahk_class #32770, ,WinActivate, Print ahk_class #32770
    WinWaitActive, Print ahk_class #32770   ; Waits until the specified window is active 
    Send !p
Return

#IfWinActive
```

or

```
; WinWait, WinTitle, WinText, Seconds, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText

WinWait, Print ahk_class #32770, WinText  ; Use Window Spy to find out a single text element of the target window 
IfWinNotActive, ...
...
```

Comment: Great, works!  Maybe specifying `ahk_class #32770` is little bit redundant – isn't it?

Comment: I see the trick was is activation. Window is immediately presented as focused (active), but it seems that it actually isn't active yet. Activation solves the problem